# Missing Merge Commits, converting SVN repo to hg

Tags: svn, merge, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I am using the included merge tool of hg to convert from an existing SVN repository. I am using a windows 7 machine with an up to date install of TortoiseHg (version 2.11.2
with Mercurial-2.9.2, Python-2.7.6, PyQt-4.10.3, Qt-4.8.5). I am using this command:

`hg convert https://[url to root of repository] [output dir] --datesort`

My problem is that the historical merges are not tracked in the resulting hg repository. Specifically, all the commits are present and appear to be anatomically correct, but the branches do not show as merged back into the default branch in hg. I've tried a parallel conversion with the git-svn tool, and it successfully tracked the merges.

Is there a way for mercurial to *automatically* identify and display the merges from, for example, a branch back to trunk, after conversion from an SVN repository?

Comment: you might have more luck with hgsubversion